# OpemXML Namespaces

Tags: .net, namespaces, openxml

How do I get the namespaces of specific nodes in the OpenXML standard?

Here is an example of using them:

```
NameTable nt = new NameTable();
XmlNamespaceManager nsManager1 = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
nsManager1.AddNamespace("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");
```

BUT

I still need to know how / where she gets the schema URIs from.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

-nomad311

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any OOXML-document is going to contain the used namespaces in the top of document.xml within the package.

You should always refer to [specifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML), but [here's](http://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/ug-oxygen/author-ooxml-doc-type.html) a short list.

Comment: Well I feel a little less smarterer than yesterday :)
Thanks, who knew they were all right there!